# Install packages using pip for updated versions of python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I recently updated from Python 3.5 to Python 3.6 and am trying to use packages that I had previously downloaded, but they are not working for the updated version of Python.  When I try to use pip, I use the command "pip install selenium" and get the message "Requirement already satisfied: selenium in /Users/Jeff/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages"  How do I add packages to the new version of Python?

Comment: `pip install package --upgrade`

Comment: Maybe `pip3.6 install package`.

Comment: @Matthias - that did the trick.  Thanks!

Comment: @Jeff: So `pip` seems to link to `pip3.5` in the Python 3.5 installation.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that your packages do have compatibility with the version of Python you're looking to use.

Next, run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` in the base directory of your Python project. This puts everything in a readable file to re-install from. If you know of any packages that require a certain version that you'll want to re-install, put `package==x.x.x` (where `package` is the package name and `x.x.x` is the version number) in the list of packages to make sure it downloads the correct version.

Run `pip uninstall -r requirements.txt -y` to uninstall all packages. Afterwards, run `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

This allows you to keep packages at the correct version for the ones you assign a version number in `requirements.txt`, while upgrading all others.